# Stack Push function only works when debugging

Tags: c, dynamic, stack, malloc

I have a problem with a push function. It's a simple push function for stack structure but most of the time doesn't work. It only works when debugging.
This is the function:

```
tError favoriteStack_push(tFavoriteStack *stack, tFavorite favorite) {
    //assert(stack!=NULL);

    tFavoriteStackNode* tmp;

    //mem_allocation of new node
    tmp=(tFavoriteStackNode*)malloc(sizeof(tmp));

    if(tmp==NULL)
        return ERR_MEMORY_ERROR;

    //copying element to new node
    tmp->e=favorite;

    //pointing next to previous first element
    tmp->next=stack->first;

    //new node is the new first node
    stack->first=tmp;

    return OK;

}
```

I can't see the mistake. 
I would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(tmp)` will return the size of the pointer, not the size of the object, maybe `sizeof(*tmp)`, but the best in my opinion is

`tmp=(tFavoriteStackNode*)malloc(sizeof(tFavoriteStackNode));`

Comment: That's it. Is sizeof(*tmp) instead of sizeof(tmp). Thank you very much!!

Comment: what i mean is that `tmp=(tFavoriteStackNode*)malloc(sizeof(tmp));` should become   `tmp=(tFavoriteStackNode*)malloc(sizeof(tFavoriteStackNode));`

Comment: The `tmp=malloc(sizeof(*tmp));` form (no cast) is generally recommended. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: People recommend `sizeof(*tmp)` since you don't have to write the type twice. But you do have to write the variable name twice.

Comment: @user253751 It doesn't matter much if you're `malloc`ing in an initialization: `t *p = malloc(sizeof(t));`,  where the type on the left and the type in the sizeof are right next to each other => easy to verify the `t` matches the `sizeof(t)`. But you could also have `t *p; /*...code...*/ p = malloc(sizeof(t))` and then if the declaration changes to `t1 *p`, the `malloc` call will be wrong and the error might not be easy to spot. `t *p; /*...code...*/ p = malloc(sizeof(*p));` won't have that problem.